# How to loop a sample with function and store output in vector?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following test sample and empty vector

```
test_sample <- rnorm(n=1:1000 , mean=3, sd=2)
empty_vector <- rep(NA,10000)
```

with the function that returns the difference of 2 sample means

```
mean_diff_sampler <- function(pop_v, n){
  sample1 <- sample(pop_v, size=n, replace = TRUE)
  sample2 <- sample(pop_v, size=n, replace = TRUE)
  mean1 <- mean(sample1)
  mean2 <- mean(sample2)
  diffmean <- mean1 - mean2
  return(diffmean)
}
```

How can I for-loop the test_sample 10000 times and use the function to find the mean difference each time, storing the output in the empty vector?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this achieves what you were hoping for:

```r
#' Compare the means of two samples of an input numeric vector.
#' 
#' @param pop_v The population vector to sample.
#' @param n The size to sample from the population vector.
mean_diff_sampler <- function(pop_v, n){
  sample1 <- sample(pop_v, size=n, replace = TRUE)
  sample2 <- sample(pop_v, size=n, replace = TRUE)
  mean1 <- mean(sample1)
  mean2 <- mean(sample2)
  diffmean <- mean1 - mean2
  return(diffmean)
}

# sample the population and fill the empty_vector
test_sample <- rnorm(n=1:1000 , mean=3, sd=2)
empty_vector <- numeric(10000)
sample_size <- 100

for (i in seq_along(empty_vector)) {
  empty_vector[[i]] <- 
    mean_diff_sampler(test_sample, sample_size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short:**
The (somewhat dirty) answer to your specific question:

```
 for (i in 1:1000) {
     diff <- mean_diff_sampler(test_sample, 40)
     empty_vector[i] <- diff
}
```

**Longer:**
The broader answer to the problem you are trying to solve

I assume that your goal is to simulate taking 2 samples from a population, take the means and then calculate the difference.
Then to repeat this process a lot of times to get a sampling distribution.

Whenever there is a `for`-loop involved, I ask myself how to do it better.

There is ready made sampling function which can replace the loop:

`infer::rep_sample_n`

It does exactly what it says: repeat sampling n times and returns a data frame with results.

(However, it requires a data frame as input as well.)

Here is the code I have come up with for this task. There is room for improvement, I would love to hear about it, but I hope the idea gets through.

1. Loading packages and creating a data frame with the population:

```
library(infer)
library(dplyr)

test_sample <- rnorm(n=1:1000 , mean=3, sd=2)
df <- data.frame(test_sample)
```

2. Defining the number of total sampling replications, which should be double the amount of desired sample pairs. `pairs` is created.

```
reps <- 200 # even number required
pairs <- 1:(reps / 2)
pairs <- sort(c(pairs, pairs))
```

3. Sampling takes place `reps = 200` times. Then the mean of each sample is calculated. Then `pairs` is added as a new column and used to calculate differences of means within each pair.

```
sampling_distribution <- rep_sample_n(df, n = 50, replace = TRUE, reps = reps) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(test_sample)) %>%
  mutate(pair = pairs) %>%
  group_by(pair) %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(mean))
```

Output:

```
head(sampling_distribution)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
   pair   diff
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1  0.463
2     2 -0.475
3     3 -0.939
4     4 -0.145
5     5 -1.03 
6     6  0.594
```

Results are loosely resembling a normal distribution (central limit theorem works, yay):

```
hist(sampling_distribution$diff, breaks = 20)
```

[image: histogram of the sampling distribution]